# jQuery - remove class from element when radio button is unchecked

Tags: jquery, forms, radio-button

I've been working on a form element replacement script – replacing normal form elements with divs that can be styled – but I've run into an issue with radio buttons.  I cannot figure out how to remove a checked replacement button's "selected" class when another button is selected.

I've included my code in this fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/zumwalt/eEvPE/3/

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: `var id = $(this).attr('id');
var radio = $('input[id="'+id+'"]');` Yikes.

Comment: Yeah, I assumed that's not the smartest move.  I'm quite new to writing this stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add the following line in your click handler to clear the `selected` class from all radios, before adding it to the one which was clicked:

```
$(".radio").removeClass("selected");
```

[**Updated fiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/eEvPE/4/)

Comment: And what if there's multiple radio buttons with different names in the same page. This would remove the class for all.

Comment: So simple.  I've been looking at this too long.  Thanks for the help.  @Interstellar_Coder - the nature of the application makes this a non-issue, but that's a good point.

Answer (score 0):

Remove classes using: http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/   or read [this already asked question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2117538/jquery-how-to-uncheck-a-radio-button)

Answer (score 0):

Remove 'selected' class from all buttons with `removeClass()` and then add to the clicked one. However you should remove class only from buttons in the same radio group. There are several ways to achieve this.

You can require all buttons to be in one `div` element and update only buttons inside it.
Or you can add class containing `name` attr from original radios to your buttons and update only buttons having this class.
Or you can add extra attribute to your buttons with value equal to the `name` attribute of original radios and update only buttons having right attribute. See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/n3PUe/