# How to toggle the check state of a radio input element on click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, radio-button

How to (un)check a radio input element on click of the element or its container?

I have tried the code below, but it does not uncheck the radio.

HTML:

```
<div class="is">
    <label><input type="radio" name="check" class="il-radio" /> Is </label>
    <img src="picture" />
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(".is label, .is ").click(function () {
    if (!$(this).find(".il-radio").attr("checked")) {
        $(this).find(".il-radio").attr("checked", "checked");
    } else if ($(this).find(".il-radio").attr("checked") == "checked") {
        $(this).find(".il-radio").removeAttr("checked");
    }
});
```

Comment: why dont you just use label in its original form? http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_label.asp

Comment: @OriesokVlassky: Because that would require every input control to have an ID, in order for the label to refer to it.  `<label><input>...</label>` is valid HTML; it should work.

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2117538/jquery-how-to-uncheck-a-radio-button

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to prevent the default behaviour. Currently, on click, the following happens:

1. `click` event fires for the container (`div.is`).
2. `click` event fires for the label.
3. Since your function toggles a state, and the event listener is called twice, the outcome is that nothing seems to happen.

Corrected code (http://jsfiddle.net/nHvsf/3/):

```
$(".is").click(function(event) {
    var radio_selector = 'input[type="radio"]',
        $radio;

    // Ignore the event when the radio input is clicked.
    if (!$(event.target).is(radio_selector)) {
        $radio = $(this).find(radio_selector);
        // Prevent the event to be triggered
        // on another element, for the same click
        event.stopImmediatePropagation();
        // We manually check the box, so prevent default
        event.preventDefault();
        $radio.prop('checked', !$radio.is(':checked'));
    }
});
$(".il-radio").on('change click', function(event) {
    // The change event only fires when the checkbox state changes
    // The click event always fires

    // When the radio is already checked, this event will fire only once,
    //   resulting in an unchecked checkbox.
    // When the radio is not checked already, this event fires twice
    //   so that the state does not change
    this.checked = !this.checked;
});
```

Comment: Can you make it so if I click on the radio it-self will check it also?

Comment: Now the picture doesn't trigger the select.

Comment: @agam360 Previously, the `event.target` property was used as a reference. That was wrong, and it's fixed now.

Comment: demo link "**Error 404**"

Comment: @Elyor Fixed broken link.

Answer (score 6):

radio buttons don't uncheck, you need to use a checkbox (type = 'checkbox')

Comment: Can you give me the proper way to do so for a radio?

Comment: a radio button is normally only unchecked if another radio button is clicked with the same "name" attribute, it's basic HTML

Comment: Radio buttons work that way. You should use Checkbox if you want a "check-uncheck" behavior

Comment: Why do you want to mangle a radio button to do something that a checkbox would do without any extra work?

Comment: @Juhana, I have two of those is classes, i need only one of them to be selected.

Comment: Checkboxes aren't mutually exclusive by default. That's why someone would want to stick with radio buttons...

Answer (score 0):

use  only html , same functionality

```
<label for="rdio"><input type="radio" name="rdio" id="rdio" class="il-radio"  /> Is </label>
```

Comment: The `for` attribute is not needed when the control is the only one within the label.