# Allow user to cancel click on a radio button without Javascript

Tags: html, radio-button

Is there a way to enable the user to cancel his click on a radio button ?

Preferably, without jQuery or even Javascript.

```
<label class='radio inline'>
    <input name='sexe' type='radio' value='1'/>
    Male
</label>
<label class='radio inline'>
    <input name='sexe' type='radio' value='2'/>
    Female
</label>
```

JSFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/dEDbN/

Comment: possible duplicate of [JQuery How to Uncheck A radio button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2117538/jquery-how-to-uncheck-a-radio-button)

Comment: Ok, thank you. In order to make my question useful to SO, I've changed the title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the reset button. I don't think there is a way to do it without trying something of ajax or jquery.