# radiobuttons - no option selected

Tags: javascript, radio-button

I am basically trying to build a simple quiz game to learn JavaScript. 
How do I make the radio buttons not have on option selected when the next question is displayed?

[See JSFiddle example here](http://jsfiddle.net/ZMqVT/)

I tried something like this but this is JQuery.

```
$('[name="ans"]').prop('checked', false);
```

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of [how to check a radio button with jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5665915/how-to-check-a-radio-button-with-jquery)

Comment: What if you supplied a hidden option and set that as the default?

Comment: Try [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2117571/858840)

Comment: @dc5 seems clear to me that OP is not wanting to us Jquery

Comment: Yeah - re-read that just now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to avoid using jQuery, you can try something like this:

```
var radios = document.getElementsByName('an');
for(i = 0; i < radios.length; i++){
    radios[i].checked = false;
}
```

[**<kbd>JSFiddle Demo</kbd>**](http://jsfiddle.net/darkajax/ze66K/)

Notice the second radio element is checked inside the HTML, but this code is executed on each `nextQ()` call

Comment: would you reccommend Jquery over my current setup? It seems to me that Jquery might be a more efficient way to do this. but I am just learning...maybe the slow way using this current way with javascript/document.getElementById

Comment: Stick with vanilla JS.  You'll end up with a better perspective of browsers and their differences.  If you want to be a little more efficient in your code, you could change your data structure a bit and store off any dom elements you'll be accessing once on initialization, then just loop through them.  Also, introduce some CSS and let it do some of the work for you.  [JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ZMqVT/16/)

Comment: @HattrickNZ Sometimes using jQuery is good for compatibility but using plain JavaScript tends to be more efficient...

Comment: @dc5 Thanks very much for that. I am ownly learning and know that there is lots of better ways of doing this. so thanks for the example to refer to!!

Comment: @dc5 these links help me understand your code a bit more how you hide and unhide stuff [link1](http://jsfiddle.net/NrGgA/) [link2](http://jsfiddle.net/6A7Lt/)

Answer (score 2):

If you're sure that your users are using up-to-date browsers, which support the DOM `document.querySelector()` method, you can use:

```
document.querySelector('input[type="radio"]:checked').checked = false;
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/ZMqVT/12/).

The benefit of `querySelector()` is that it returns only the first element that matches the selector pattern (assuming it matches *any* element) (though if you want to get *all* the matching elements there's `document.querySelectorAll()`).

The `document` can, of course, be replaced with am element-node reference (to restrict the method to searching only the form, for example, rather than the whole document).

References:

- [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelector).
- [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelectorAll).

Comment: Excellent; and you're very welcome indeed; I'm glad to have been of some help! =)