# How to uncheck radio button upon double clicking?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want this functionality:

When user clicks on already checked radio button, it should uncheck it.

I'm trying this code but no luck.

```
$(document).on('mouseup','className',function(){
    if ($(this).is(':checked')){
        $(this).prop('checked', false);
    }
});
```

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2117538/jquery-how-to-uncheck-a-radio-button

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try

```
$(document).on('dblclick','.className',function(){
    if(this.checked){
        $(this).prop('checked', false);
    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/596DF/)

Answer (score 1):

Try This

**HTML**

```
<input type="radio" class="rdCheck" checked="checked" text="click me"/> click me
```

**JS**

```
$('.rdCheck').dblclick(function(){

          if($(this).is(':checked'))
          {
             $(this).removeAttr('checked');
          }
});
```

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/UJ8n4/2/)**

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[.dblclick()](http://api.jquery.com/dblclick/)**:

```
$(document).on('dblclick','className',function(){
    if ($(this).is(':checked')){
        $(this).prop('checked', false);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this way:

```
$(document).on('dblclick','.yourCls',function(){
   if(this.checked){ // if true
      $(this).prop('checked', !this.checked); // then !this.checked == false
   }
});
```

---

Well you have to check for its checked state `this.checked` returns boolean values `true/false`. if `true` the uncheck it or else check it.