# How To set the value of radio button to empty when it is deslected

Tags: javascript, jquery

Please help me to come out of this

I have already this part:

```
$(':input[type=radio]',taskClass).not(':button, :submit, :reset, :hidden').val('')
.removeAttr('checked');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this
if radio button is deselected, then clear its value

```
if( $(':input[type=radio]').is(':checked') == false ) {

   $(this).attr('checked',false).val('');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)**:

```
$(':input[type=radio]',taskClass).not(':button, :submit, :reset, :hidden').val('').prop('checked',false);
```

Comment: because prop('checked') , is property NOT ATTRIBUTE :)

Answer (score 0):

Check out here is good post [How to uncheck a radio button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2117538/jquery-how-to-uncheck-a-radio-button)

Use following syntax

```
 $(this).prop('checked', false);
```

Answer (score 0):

I just located the radio buttons with the name

```
$("[name=radio-button-name]").prop('checked', false);
```