# Unchecking a radio button function

Tags: javascript, html

i want to uncheck a radio button and i used this `$("#second").attr('checked', false);`
 if i put it in a function and then i call it with a button it works but if i called it in this function

```
function myFunction() {
  var choice= document.getElementsByName("radiob");
  var len=choice.length//number of radio buttons
  var wrong;
  var arrayq=["test1","test2"];
  var arraya=["صاروخ","12"];
  var j=0;
  for(i=0;i<len;i++){
    if(choice[i].checked){
      if(choice[i].value==arraya[j]){
        document.getElementById("question").innerHTML = arrayq[j];
        j++;    
        //HERE
        $("#second").attr('checked', false);
        document.getElementById("f").innerHTML ="6";
        document.getElementById("s").innerHTML ="7";
        document.getElementById("t").innerHTML ="12";
      } else {
        wrong++;//number of wrong answers
        document.getElementById("question").innerHTML = arrayq[j];
        j++;
        document.getElementById("f").innerHTML ="6";
        document.getElementById("s").innerHTML ="7";
        document.getElementById("t").innerHTML ="12";
      }
    }
  }
}
```

i don't know why but whenever i put this code `$("#second").attr('checked', false);`
 or an alert message under this if statement `if(choice[i].value==arraya[j])` it does not work and i also used `$("#second").prop('checked', false;);`. please keep in mind that i'm a beginner and these options are just to experiment.

Comment: `$("#second")` will only select one radio with `id` second.. can you add the html and explain what you're trying to do..?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to uncheck a radio button?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2117538/how-to-uncheck-a-radio-button)

Comment: @TJ No i know i'm just trying to check if it works or not.

Comment: @Juhana I already saw it and i have tried it and it didn't work.

Comment: @user3721585 "if it works or not" if what works..? unless you explain what you're trying to do how do we know what's wrong..? how do we know whether you even have such an element in your html unless you share it..?

Comment: @T J i tried `$(this).prop('checked', false);` and `$("input[name=checkbox]:checked").each(function () {

//if your checkbox is checked then you can do what ever you want to do with it inside here,or uncheck it

  });` and they both didn't work

Answer (score 0):

```
$("input[name=checkbox]:checked").each(function () {

//if your checkbox is checked then you can do what ever you want to do with it inside here,or uncheck it

  });
```

Comment: But isn't this for check boxes only! not radio buttons? and i tried it but unfortunately it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You miss a semicolon here

```
var len=choice.length//number of radio buttons
```

And it is

```
$("#second").prop('checked', false);
```

not

```
$("#second").prop('checked', false;);
```

You may use chrome's console to get debug information.

Comment: Semicolons in JavaScript are optional (it is however,  good practise to use them).

Answer (score 0):

i figured out why it doesn't uncheck the radio button in the if statement, and the reason why is that it never goes in the if statement the whole time it goes to the else statement.
sorry it's a stupid mistake, i apologize for wasting your time.