# Makes checkbox like radiobutton WITH uncheck available

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I need to have 2 checkbox work as radiobutton, but I can't use radiobutton cause I want to make uncheck available

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".gps-garmin").click(function() {
  selectedBox = this.id;
  $(".gps-garmin").each(function() {
    if ( this.id == selectedBox )
    {
      this.checked = true;
    }
    else
    {
      this.checked = false;
    };
  });
 });
});
```

```
<td><input type="checkbox" id="garmin" value="garmin" class="gps-garmin"></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" id="gps" value="gps" class="gps-garmin"></td>
```

Actually my checkbox are working exactly like radio button, I found this code here, but I need to make uncheck possible

Comment: `I can't use radiobutton cause I want to make uncheck available` In this case use 3 radio buttons. 1 for each of these options: `Garmin`, `GPS` and `None` This makes the validation logic simpler too, as then all groups must be chosen from, so theres no possibility of a user missing out an option

Comment: I don't want a none button it's useless in my case, I got other checkbox after this that didn't need this feature

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(".gps-garmin").click(function() {
  var check = $(this).prop('checked');
  $(".gps-garmin").prop('checked',false);
  $(this).prop('checked', (check) ? true : false);
  });
```

Comment: It's working like my code, but I can't uncheck if I checked

Comment: What was your requirement we can't get you @Sydowh

Comment: @RajeshBaskaran I just need this but with uncheck possible

Comment: I've edit my code, try it. Seems it works as you need.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in [How-to-uncheck-a-radiobutton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2117538/how-to-uncheck-a-radio-button), you should be able to clear a radio-button by using plain js or jQuery

For example in case of using plain js (copied from the linked answer):

```
this.checked = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this You trying:
$(".gps-garmin").click(function() {

if($(this).prop("checked") == true){

$(".gps-garmin").prop('checked',false);

```
$(this).prop('checked',true);
```

}
else if($(this).prop("checked") == false){

```
$(".gps-garmin").prop('checked',false);


        }
```

});