# How to change my code to uncheck radio button from javascript to jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, radio-button

I have this javascript code to uncheck the radio button which is working fine

```
function uncheckRadio(){
    const radioBtns = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="choices"]');
    for(const btn of radioBtns){
        if(btn.checked){
            btn.checked = false;
        }
    }
}
```

What would this function look like if rewritten into jQuery?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to uncheck a radio button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2117538/how-to-uncheck-a-radio-button)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to think of the selector in jQuery. The selector in your case is the name.

Secondly, you need to think of a way to loop through your elements. This can be done by the `.each()` function in jQuery.

Use the `.prop()` function to uncheck the radio button by setting the property to `false`.

**jQuery Example:**

```
function uncheckRadio(){
    $('input[name^="choices"]').each(function() {
        $(this).prop('checked', false)
    });
}
```

Comment: thanks Martin Sir for the answer with good explanation,it solved my issue ...thanks

Comment: if you want to do in one liner then $('input[name="choices"]:checked').prop("checked", false);