# How to select only one checkbox instead of being able to select more than one? (react)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input, checkbox

I would like to only be able to select a single checkbox and not all or more than one. I would like to use checkbox instead of radio because I can disable it without having to mark another radio

```
     <C.SingleCard>
            <h2>Pizza</h2>
            <div>
                <hr />
                <h3>Flavors</h3>
                <hr />
            </div>
            <div>
                <h4>Pepperoni</h4>
                <input type="checkbox" name='flavor' />
            </div>
            <div>
                <h4>Chicken</h4>
                <input type="checkbox"  name='flavor' />
            </div>
            <div>
                <h4>Bacon</h4>
                <input type="checkbox"  name='flavor'  />
            </div>
            <div>
                <button>Add</button>
            </div>
        </C.SingleCard>
```

Comment: Why not radio buttons ? if you're just worried about presentation/view it can be changed to with css

Comment: How could I make it so that I can disable a radio button without necessarily having to select another one? in the simplest way possible

Comment: With radio button you can always select one option only, i am not getting when you want to disable buttons ?

Comment: Once I refresh the page, all my radios are unmarked, but when I mark a radio, I wish I could deselect that radio without having to mark another radio, you know? just 'no value'

Comment: Got it, you can look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2117538/how-to-uncheck-a-radio-button, hope this helps

Comment: do you know any way to do this in a simpler way using state react?

Answer (score 2):

Here's the simplest way I can think of:

Put the options in an array and just keep track of the selected index. Set the index to null if the user selected the same index. Use the `index` parameter of `map` to set `checked=true` on the selected box. The `onChange` callback will trigger when the user selects one of the boxes, you can ignore the event parameter and just pass the index of the box.

```
const options = ['pepperoni', 'chicken', 'bacon'];

export default function App() {
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState(null);

  function onChange(i) {
    setSelected((prev) => (i === prev ? null : i));
  }

  function whatDidIPick() {
    console.log(options[selected] || 'nothing');
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {options.map((o, i) => (
        <label key={i}>
          {o}
          <input
            type="checkbox"
            checked={i === selected}
            onChange={() => onChange(i)}
          />
        </label>
      ))}
      <br />
      <button onClick={whatDidIPick}>Log what I picked</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-1uwfcq?file=App.tsx

Comment: Good answer, you can add bit of summary of logic that will make it great 