# make checkbox behave like radio buttons with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I need to manipulate the behavior of the check boxes with javascript. They should basically behave like radio buttons (only one selectable at a time, plus unselect any previous selections).

The problem is that I can't use plain radio buttons in first place, because the name attribute for each radio button would be different.

**I know** its not the ultimate and shiniest solutions to make an apple look like a pear, and w3c wouldn't give me their thumbs for it, but it would be a better solution right now than to change the core php logic of the entire cms structure ;-)

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Using jQuery: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/881166/jquery-checkboxes-like-radiobuttons

Comment: Are you using a framework such (e.g. jQuery) or not. I would not tell you to add jQuery or any other framework to your project for a simple task such as this one, unless you're using one.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

HTML :

```
<label><input type="checkbox" name="cb1" class="chb" /> CheckBox1</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="cb2" class="chb" /> CheckBox2</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="cb3" class="chb" /> CheckBox3</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="cb4" class="chb" /> CheckBox4</label>
```

jQuery :

```
$(".chb").change(function() {
    $(".chb").prop('checked', false);
    $(this).prop('checked', true);
});
```

if you want user can unchecked selected item :

```
$(".chb").change(function() {
    $(".chb").not(this).prop('checked', false);
});
```

**Demo :**

http://jsfiddle.net/44Zfv/724/

Comment: nice fiddle, + if you want to uncheck the checkbox again (this code is almost perfect except not allowing unchecking all) add this: if($(this).attr('checked'))

Comment: Note that .attr is no longer working, use .prop("checked") instead for newer versions of jQuery

Comment: can be simplified to `$(".chb").change(function()`, rather than `$(".chb").each(function(){ $(this).change(function()`, but nice.

Comment: @D.A.V.O.O.D  5 years on.. But the code doesn't work now - can someone update it? thanks.

Comment: Wow thanks for answering back... Just checked again - it's not working for me...? The checkboxes are working like regular checkboxes - not radios... You sure it's working for you?? I have since found another solution... Thanks

Comment: @Ben you say right, jquery file not loading in demo, i updated demo, you can see in updated answer ! thanks for your report

Comment: @kubilay, what did you mean by `add this: if($(this).attr('checked'))`? Where should it be added?

Comment: This works great, I use these checkboxes to pass the value as url parameter. As soon as I click through the boxes, the last two values are always passed as url parameter, not the very last only. Any idea, why?

Comment: Fiddle which allows unchecking of a box. I used it for filters http://jsfiddle.net/1hm7Lcf8/

Answer (score 7):

This is a better option as it allows unchecking also:

```
$(".cb").change(function () {
    $(".cb").not(this).prop('checked', false);
});
```

Answer (score 6):

There are many ways to do this. This is a clickhandler (*plain js*) for a div containing a number of checkboxes:

```
function cbclick(e){
   e = e || event;
   var cb = e.srcElement || e.target;
   if (cb.type !== 'checkbox') {return true;}
   var cbxs = document.getElementById('radiocb')
               .getElementsByTagName('input'), 
       i    = cbxs.length;
    while(i--) {
        if (cbxs[i].type 
             && cbxs[i].type == 'checkbox' 
             && cbxs[i].id !== cb.id) {
          cbxs[i].checked = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Here's [a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/TTZqa/).

Answer (score 5):

I kept it simple...

```
<html>
<body>

<script>
function chbx(obj)
{
var that = obj;
   if(document.getElementById(that.id).checked == true) {
      document.getElementById('id1').checked = false;
      document.getElementById('id2').checked = false;
      document.getElementById('id3').checked = false;
      document.getElementById(that.id).checked = true;
   }
}
</script>

<form action="your action" method="post">

<Input id='id1' type='Checkbox' Name ='name1' value ="S" onclick="chbx(this)"><br />
<Input id='id2' type='Checkbox' Name ='name2' value ="S" onclick="chbx(this)"><br />
<Input id='id3' type='Checkbox' Name ='name3' value ="S" onclick="chbx(this)"><br />

<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Some supporting information on how your approach works may be useful in this case

Comment: that has helped me in a hundred problems

Answer (score 4):

**Just in case it helps someone else**

I was having the same situation where my client needed to have a `checkbox` behaving like a `radio button`. But to me it was meaningless to use a `checkbox` and make it act like `radio button` and it was very complex for me as I was using so many `checkboxes` in a `GridView` Control.

**My Solution:** 
 So, I styled a `radio button` look like a `checkbox` and took the help of `grouping` of radio buttons.

Comment: This [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279421/can-you-style-an-html-radio-button-to-look-like-a-checkbox) should be relevant to your answer

Answer (score 4):

@DJafari's answer doesn't let unchecking the checkbox. So I've updated it like this:

```
$(".chb").change(function(e) {

 //Getting status before unchecking all
  var status = $(this).prop("checked");

  $(".chb").prop('checked', false);
  $(this).prop('checked', true);

 //false means checkbox was checked and became unchecked on change event, so let it stay unchecked
  if (status === false) {
    $(this).prop('checked', false);
  }

});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mapetek/nLtb0q1e/4/

Answer (score 1):

You could give the group of checkboxes you need to behave like this a common class, then use the class to attach the following event handler:

```
function clickReset ()
{
    var isChecked = false,
        clicked = $(this),
        set = $('.' + clicked.attr ('class') + ':checked').not (clicked);

    if (isChecked = clicked.attr ('checked'))
    {
        set.attr ('checked', false);
    }
    return true;
}

$(function ()
{
    $('.test').click (clickReset);
});
```

Note: This is pretty me just shooting from the hip, I've not tested this and it might need tweaking to work.

I would advise that you do look into finding a way of doing this with radio buttons if you can, as radios are the proper tool for the job.  Users expect checkboxes to behave like checkboxes, not radios, and if they turn javascript off they can force through input into the server side script that you weren't expecting.

EDIT: Fixed function so that uncheck works properly and added a JS Fiddle link.

http://jsfiddle.net/j53gd/1/

Comment: when click on a checked checkbox, checkbox doesn't must lose checked

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<body>

<form action="#" method="post">
Radio 1: <input type="radio" name="radioMark" value="radio 1" /><br />
Radio 2: <input type="radio" name="radioMark" value="radio 2" /><br />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Ultimately you can use brackets with the name attribute to create an array of radio input like so:

```
<input type="radio" name="radioMark[]" value="radio1" />Radio 1
<input type="radio" name="radioMark[]" value="radio2" />Radio 2
<input type="radio" name="radioMark[]" value="radio3" />Radio 3
<input type="radio" name="radioMark[]" value="radio4" />Radio 4
```

What matters to transfer in the end are whats in the value attribute. Your names do not have to be different at all for each radio button. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

In Simple JS.
Enjoy !

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
        function onChoiceChange(obj) {
            // Get Objects
            var that=obj,
                triggerChoice = document.getElementById(that.id),
                domChoice1 = document.getElementById("Choice1"),
                domChoice2 = document.getElementById("Choice2");
            // Apply
            if (triggerChoice.checked && triggerChoice.id === "Choice1") 
                domChoice2.checked=false;
            if (triggerChoice.checked && triggerChoice.id === "Choice2") 
                domChoice1.checked=false;
            // Logout
            var log = document.getElementById("message");
            log.innerHTML += "<br>"+ (domChoice1.checked ? "1" : "0") + ":" + (domChoice2.checked ? "1" : "0");
            // Return !
            return that.checked;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 id="title">Title</h1>
    <label><input type="checkbox" onclick="onChoiceChange(this)" id="Choice1" />Choice #1</label> 
    <label><input type="checkbox" onclick="onChoiceChange(this)" id="Choice2" />Choice #2</label>
    <hr>
    <div id="message"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please include some explanation of why you think your code solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<form id="form" action="#">
            <input name="checkbox1" type="checkbox" />
            <input name="checkbox2" type="checkbox" />
            <input name="checkbox3" type="checkbox" />
            <input name="checkbox4" type="checkbox" />
            <input name="checkbox5" type="checkbox" />
            <input name="checkbox6" type="checkbox" />
            <input name="checkbox7" type="checkbox" />
            <input name="checkbox8" type="checkbox" />
            <input name="checkbox9" type="checkbox" />
            <input name="checkbox10" type="checkbox" />
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"/>
        </form>
```

and this is the javascript

```
(function () {
    function checkLikeRadio(tag) {
        var form = document.getElementById(tag);//selecting the form ID 
        var checkboxList = form.getElementsByTagName("input");//selecting all checkbox of that form who will behave like radio button
        for (var i = 0; i < checkboxList.length; i++) {//loop thorough every checkbox and set there value false. 
            if (checkboxList[i].type == "checkbox") {
                checkboxList[i].checked = false;
            }
            checkboxList[i].onclick = function () {
                checkLikeRadio(tag);//recursively calling the same function again to uncheck all checkbox
                checkBoxName(this);// passing the location of selected checkbox to another function. 
            };
        }
    }

    function checkBoxName(id) {
        return id.checked = true;// selecting the selected checkbox and maiking its value true; 
    }
    window.onload = function () {
        checkLikeRadio("form");
    };
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

I like [D.A.V.O.O.D's Answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5839884/make-checkbox-behave-like-radio-buttons-with-javascript#answer-5839924), but it relies on classes on the checkbox, which should not be needed.

As checkboxes tend to be related in that they will have the same (field) name, or a name which make them part of an array, then using that to decide which other checkboxes to untick would be a better solution.

```
$(document)
  .on('change','input[type="checkbox"]',function(e){
    var $t = $(this);
    var $form = $t.closest('form');
    var name = $t.attr('name');
    var selector = 'input[type="checkbox"]';
    var m = (new RegExp('^(.+)\\[([^\\]]+)\\]$')).exec( name );
    if( m ){
      selector += '[name^="'+m[1]+'["][name$="]"]';
    }else{
      selector += '[name="'+name+'"]';
    }
    $(selector, $form).not($t).prop('checked',false);
  });
```

[This code on jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/lucanos/ex381ftj/)

Answer (score 0):

Using Knockout JS

```js
var viewModel = { 
        isMale: ko.observable(false),
        isFemale: ko.observable(false),
    };

    $(document).ready(function(){
        ko.applyBindings(viewModel)
    });

    function setCheckBox() {
        viewModel.isFemale(false)
        viewModel.isMale(false)
    };
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox" id="chkMale" name="male" data-bind="checked: isMale" class="gender" onclick="setCheckBox(this)"/>
<label for="chkMale"> MALE</label>
        
<input type="checkbox" id="chkFemale" name="female" data-bind="checked: isFemale" class="gender" onclick="setCheckBox(this)"/>
<label for="chkFemale"> FEMALE</label>
```