# How to use javascript to checked and unchecked with function onclick like this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

How to use javascript to `checked` and `unchecked` with function `onclick` like this ?

http://jsfiddle.net/A4wxX/98/

First, When you checked `checkbox id="yyy"` , `checkbox id="yyy"` wil `Checked` and `checkbox id="xxx"` wil `Unchecked`

And then, When you checked `checkbox id="xxx"` ,`checkbox id="xxx"` wil `Checked` `checkbox id="yyy"` wil `Unchecked`

on my code i must to double checked on checkbox for do that, how can i apply my code for single click ?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
function SetCard() {
    var xxx_val = document.getElementById('xxx').checked 
    var yyy_val = document.getElementById('yyy').checked
    if(xxx_val === true)
    {
        document.getElementById('yyy').checked = false; 
    }
    if(yyy_val === true)
    {
        document.getElementById('xxx').checked = false;        
    }      
}    
</script>

<input type="checkbox" id="xxx" onclick="SetCard()" checked> xxx
<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="yyy" onclick="SetCard()"> yyy
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5839884/make-checkbox-behave-like-radio-buttons-with-javascript answer here will help you

Comment: It seems like you are looking for the functionality of a radiobutton http://www.w3schools.com/HTML/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_radio

Comment: If you have two options only and you need to give one option to check then use radio button instead of check-box
Use following link to customize your radio button
http://fronteed.com/iCheck/

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" id="xxx" onclick="SetCard(event)" checked> xxx
<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="yyy" onclick="SetCard(event)"> yyy
```

JS

```
function SetCard(e) {
    if (e && e.target) {
        if (e.target.id === 'xxx') {
            document.getElementById('yyy').checked = false;
        }
        else if (e.target.id === 'yyy') {
            document.getElementById('xxx').checked = false;
        }
    }
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/95pnsq3q/

Comment: can i use only `onclick="SetCard()"`

Comment: No way I can think of off hand.  You must know which checkbox was clicked to know which should be toggled.

Answer (score 0):

JS :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.checkbox').click(function(){
     $('input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked',false)
     $(this).prop('checked',true)
  });    

})
```

HTML :

```
<input type="checkbox" id="xxx" class="checkbox"  checked> xxx
<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="yyy" class="checkbox"> yyy
```