# different boxes with different checkboxs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

Here's my example: http://hamzakhan.name/dev/eric/options/five/fiveage.html

As you can see, there are two checkboxes in each box. I tried adding this javascript from [make checkbox behave like radio buttons with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5839884/make-checkbox-behave-like-radio-buttons-with-javascript) by adding this script under the html form code:

```
<script>
$(".agecb").each(function()
{
    $(this).change(function()
    {
        $(".agecb").prop('checked',false);
        $(this).prop('checked',true);
    });
});
</script>
```

but it's not working. As you see, when I try to click on one checkbox and then click on another checkbox in the next panel, the first one unchecked. How do I fix that? I want it to work across each panel.

Comment: Please post your example HTML here, not on a live website.

Comment: Why don't you just use radio buttons, instead of making checkboxes that act like radio buttons.

Comment: I did check out many methods on both checkboxes and radio buttons and finally settled on that code that make the checkboxes act like radio buttons . It seems like best method for what I was looking for. Also thanks to PeterKA for his help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bear in mind that there is context; in your case each pair of checkboxes is within a form element:

```
$('.agecb').on('change', function() {
    this.checked = true;
    $(this).closest('form').find('.agecb').not(this).prop('checked', false);
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/r1a3dj9m/)

Answer (score 3):

You need to uncheck only the other checkboxes in the same form, not all the checkboxes. You also don't need to use `.each()`, jQuery does that automatically when you call an event binding function (and most other functions that make sense to operate on all elements in a collection).

```
$(".agecb").change(function() {
    $(this).closest(".ageform").find(".agecb").prop('checked', false);
    $(this).prop('checked', true);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make a "one group checkbox", give them the same name as describe in the documentation http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_checked.asp

```
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike"> I have a bike<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car" checked> I have a car<br>
```

But, if you want to make only one item selected in each "group", you better use radio button.