# How to make only one checkbox checked in multiple checkboxes based on specific parent in jquery

Tags: java, jquery, html

Here I have number of `checkboxes` whose structure are like parent and child.Here I can check only one checkbox based on parent,Suppose for `Parent1` I checked `Child11` again when I checked `Child12`,`Child11` should unchecked similar to radio button.

Again same thing should be happen for `Parent2`,but if I `check/uncheck` any child in `Parent2`,children's of `parent1` should not disturbed.

Can anyone please help me,here is the code below

### HTML

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="details">
<ul>
<li>Parent1</li>
<li>
<ul>
<li><input type="checkbox"><span>Child11</span></li>
<li><input type="checkbox"><span>Child12</span></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>

<ul>
<li>Parent2</li>
<li>
<ul>
<li><input type="checkbox"><span>Child21</span></li>
<li><input type="checkbox"><span>Child22</span></li>
<li><input type="checkbox"><span>Child23</span></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
ul li{
  list-style-type:none;
  }
```

Comment: Where is your javascript/jquery? What have you tried?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [make checkbox behave like radio buttons with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5839884/make-checkbox-behave-like-radio-buttons-with-javascript)

Comment: and why not using radio buttons to do so. That is what they are meant for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(".p1chb").change(function()
                                  {
                                      $(".p1chb").prop('checked',false);
                                      $(this).prop('checked',true);
                                  });
                                  
                                  ///above for parent 1, below for parent 2.
 $(".p2chb").change(function()
                                  {
                                      $(".p2chb").prop('checked',false);
                                      $(this).prop('checked',true);
                                  });
```

```css
ul li{
  list-style-type:none;
  }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="details">
<ul>
<li>Parent1</li>
<li>
<ul>
<li><input type="checkbox" id="Child11" name="Parent1" value="Child11" class="p1chb"
         checked>
  <label for="Child11">Child11</li>
<li><input type="checkbox" id="Child12" name="Parent1" value="Child12" class="p1chb"
         unchecked>
  <label for="Child12">Child12</label></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>

<ul>
<li>Parent2</li>
<li>
<ul>
<li><input type="checkbox" id="Child21" name="Parent2" value="Child21" class="p2chb"
         checked>
  <label for="Child21">Child21</label></li>
<li><input type="checkbox" id="Child22" name="Parent2" value="Child22" class="p2chb"
         unchecked>
  <label for="Child21">Child22</label></li>
<li><input type="checkbox" id="Child23" name="Parent2" value="Child23" class="p2chb"
         unchecked>
  <label for="Child23">Child23</label></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
</div>

<div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer,can we do it for checkbox with jquery

Comment: changed to checkboxes with jquery

Comment: Thanks for your answer here .p1chb this class I may not have since all the <ul></ul>  are genarating dynamically in my project so there may be n number of <ul></ul>,I mean parent child,here in example its 2 but in my project its may be 3,4,5 etc depend on some API.

Comment: mainly was done for example, just make sure the classes are not the same for different sections of check boxes, ie, parent 1 and parent 2 should have different class names for input .

Comment: I got your point but even I also don't know how many parent child will be there,those will generate based on some condition.so in that case how to write script

Comment: i only have a concept for how to do such a thing, it would take me hours to actually code and figure out, and it may depend on your code. To my understanding if you were  pulling your parent items from an api, you could create a for loop which dynamically renders your css, adding a new class and for each item in the .length of your object. the names then would be specific to each iteration, thus would keep everything separate . good luck on that one.