# JQuery: Checkbox as radiobutton, without default selection

Tags: jquery

I have a dynamically generated list, of random length from zero items up, where each item includes by a checkbox. Unlike radio buttons, all of the checkboxes can be unchecked, but like radio buttons only one can *be* checked. To enforce this, I am using JQuery (based on the answer given here: [jQuery - checkboxes like radiobuttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/881166/jquery-checkboxes-like-radiobuttons))

My code as it currently stands is:

```
var $radiocheck = $('input.radiocheck');
$radiocheck.click(function() {
    if($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $(this).attr('checked', false);
    }
    else if($(this).not(':checked')) {
        $radiocheck.removeAttr('checked');
        $(this).attr('checked', true);
    }
});
```

...but it doesn't work (checkboxes remain unchecked on click). Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Add an extra radio button for "none of the above". You run the risk of confusing your users if you cause checkboxes to behave like something else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var $radiocheck = $('input.radiocheck');

$radiocheck.on('click', function() {
    $radiocheck.not(this).prop('checked', false);
    this.checked = this.checked===true ? true:false; // to toggle, otherwise just set to true
});​
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/gYR4a/4/)

Comment: awesome answer, but use `.prop("checked", false);`  to replace .attr()   call.  [.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)

Answer (score 1):

**One:**

```
    var $radiocheck = $('input.radiocheck');

    $radiocheck.on('click', function() {
        $radiocheck.not(this).attr('checked', false);
        this.checked = this.checked;
    });
```

**[DEMO: One](http://jsfiddle.net/xTFXT/4/)**

**Two:**

```
   var $radiocheck = $('input.radiocheck');

   $radiocheck.on('click', function() {
     $radiocheck.not(this).attr('checked', false).find(this).attr('checked', this.checked);
   });
```

[**DEMO: Two**](http://jsfiddle.net/xTFXT/5/)

Answer (score 1):

Another answer using adeneo's approach but without using css classes for selection:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var $radiocheck = $(":checkbox");
   $radiocheck.on('click', function() {
     $radiocheck.not(this).attr('checked', false);
     this.checked = this.checked === true ? true : false;
   });
 });
```

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/petersk8/uf63csqr/)