# Is there a way to allow only one check box on each row to me checked?

Tags: php, html, forms, input, radio-button

hi i am trying to create a form where user selects either am or pm sessions for each day of the week except Monday where only am is available.

my code is currently:

```
    <table border="0" id="EnrollPreSes">        
    <tr>
        <td>Day</td>
        <td>AM <br/> 8:30 - 11:30 </td>
        <td>PM <br/> 12:00 - 3:00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Monday</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="Prefses[]" id="mam" value="MonAM"></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Tuesday</td>
        <td>
                 <input type="radio" name="Prefses" value="TueAM">  
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="radio" name="Prefses" value="TuePM">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Wednesday</td>
        <td>
            <input type="radio" name="Prefses" value="WedAM">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="radio" name="Prefses" value="WedPM">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

and so on for the rest of the week, is there a way to allow only an am or pm slot for each day to be selected and then be sent to my php script as an array?

Comment: Why not just use a radio button for the AM/PM selection?

Comment: would that work tho as they can have for instance 
monday am 
tuesday pm 
wednesday Pm
thursday am 
friday am ?

Comment: yes each row would have their own linked check boxes just means you'll have to request 7 days worth of post vars (only 7 as 2 checkboxes respond as one when linked)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give each rows radio buttons the same name, jsFiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/QTCy2/8/

```
<form id="EnrollPreSes">
<table border="0" id="EnrollPreSes">        
    <tr>
        <td>Day</td>
        <td>AM <br/> 8:30 - 11:30 </td>
        <td>PM <br/> 12:00 - 3:00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Monday</td>
        <td>
        <input type="radio" name="monday" value="MonAM">  
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="radio" name="monday" value="MonPM">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Tuesday</td>
        <td>
                 <input type="radio" name="tuesday" value="TueAM">  
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="radio" name="tuesday" value="TuePM">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Wednesday</td>
        <td>
            <input type="radio" name="wednesday" value="WedAM">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="radio" name="wednesday" value="WedPM">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

       <input type="submit" value="Submit">

</form>

$(function(){
    $('#EnrollPreSes').on('submit', function() {
       alert($(this).serialize()); //Send to your PHP script
        return false; 
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It'd be easier to have one Am radio and one Pm radio, but if you really want it:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input > radio').click(function () {
        $(this).siblings().removeAttr('checked');
    )}
)}
```

I know you've a checkbox for monday so it could be adapted to accommodate both.

Comment: would this just be added into <script> tags on the page? as im new to jquery

Comment: exactly. but you'll have to include jquery aswell :) its that simple

Answer (score 0):

A pointed out in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/881166/jquery-checkboxes-like-radiobuttons) answer using jquery you can add class unique to your checkbox and then:

```
var $unique = $('input.unique');
$unique.click(function() {
$unique.filter(':checked').not(this).removeAttr('checked');
```

});

Comment: between he script tags in the head of your document <head><script></script></head> and don't forget to add class="unique" to your checkbox and include jquery at the top of the page <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>