# Checkbox value in array javascript

Tags: javascript, checkbox

I have a list of checkbox, my goal is to create and store the value of checkbox only the one that is checked. Can someone guide me with this?

```
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Airplane"/>
```

Comment: If you want only one out of the three, use radio buttons.

Comment: What if more than one is checked?

Comment: Yes, if the user checked two of them, I only want to store the 2 value of the checkbox that is checked

Comment: @user2310422 Please be clear on your question, you want to store it in PHP array, Js array or something else..

Comment: HTML 5 localStorage ?

Comment: If u have a list of values falling under a category of which you want one option to be selected. I suggest you use the listbox itself.

Comment: I think, Actually he want to do same functionality with radio button type single checked. If any checkbox checked than other checkebox remove checked.

Answer (score 3):

You really should show some code of what you have tried. You can get the checkboxes by name, then loop over them and collect the values of those that are checked:

```
<script>

function getCheckboxValues(form) {
  var values = [];
  var vehicles = form.vehicle;

  for (var i=0, iLen=vehicles.length; i<iLen; i++) {
    if (vehicles[i].checked) {
      values.push(vehicles[i].value);
    }
  }
  // Do something with values
  alert("Vehicles: " + values.join(', '));
  return values;
}

</script>

<form onsubmit="getCheckboxValues(this); return false;">
  Bike: <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike"><br>
  Car: <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car"><br>
  Aeroplane: <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Airplane"><br>
  <input type="reset"> <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: form.vechicle is null

Comment: @GiorgosFandomas–not in any browser I've tested, nor those in general use that have supported scripting for about the last 20 years. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Please do one thing change name `vehicle` to `vehicle[]`

```
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle[]" value="Bike"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle[]" value="Car"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle[]" value="Airplane"/>
```

at post you will receive the array of checked vehicle values and you can store it to DB

in `$_POST['vehicle']`

Comment: there's no mention of Server Side language.. not good to answer on assumptions...!

Comment: but its under category of php

Comment: @Ian hey mate earlier it was in under php tag

Comment: Using fieldnames with '[]' at the end causes trouble when you want to process the fields in javascript like in RobG's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Look on live demo

http://jsbin.com/uwewi

```
<script>
$('input[name=vahicle]').click(function() {
    $('input[name=vahicle]:checked').not(this).removeAttr('checked');
});
</script>
```

**OR**

[jQuery - checkboxes like radiobuttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/881166/jquery-checkboxes-like-radiobuttons)

If you want to get only one value among this than please you `radio` button its best way.

```
<input type="radio" name="vehicle" value="Bike"/>
<input type="radio" name="vehicle" value="Car"/>
<input type="radio" name="vehicle" value="Airplane"/>
```

**OR**

If you want to go with `checkbox` than you below jQuery;

```
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Airplane"/>
<script>
$('input[name=vahicle]').click(function(){
    $('input[name=vahicle]').removeAttr('checked');
    $(this).attr('checked', true);

});
</script>
```

Hope this will help you...!!

Answer (score -2):

If you use jQuery:

```
var vehicles = [];
$("input:checked").each(function() {
  vehicles.push($(this).val());
});

console.log(vehicles);
```

Comment: Or even simpler: `var vehicles = $("input:checked").map(function () { return this.value; }).get();`

Comment: Yeah, I see that jQuery tag…

Comment: @RobG Doesn't jQuery come standard with browsers nowadays? ;-)

Answer (score -2):

**Updated Answer**

```
var input = document.getElementsByTagName('input')
,   value = {0:'', 1:'', 2:''}
,   x = input.length--
,   array
,   box
;
function handle (x) {

 input[x].onchange = function () {
   box      = input[x];
   value[x] = box.checked ? box.value : '';
   array    = [value[0], value[1], value[2]];

   console.log(array);       
 };
}

while (x) handle(--x);
```

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zqyhP/4/)