# checkboxes behave like radiobuttons with different names

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, radio-button

i have a problem, which might be easy for you guys. Im new in jquery and trying to do a form (calculator) of selectboxes, checkboxes and 3 radiobuttons (with 3 same names, just one or none can be checkable).

When i submit the form (at the first time), the values of each inputs stay the same as I wanted to. But when I submit it the second time without refreshing/resetting, the radiobutton which was checked before disappears and even when I reclick a radiobutton without refreshing and submit it, the value cant maintained by php.

So I decided to change the radio buttons to checkboxes, and that is where I need your help.

I need 3 checkboxes which can be selected just one or none of them with different "names".

```
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox8" value="1" name="8" <?php if(isset($_POST['8']) && $_POST['8'] == '1') echo 'checked="checked"';?> />
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox9" value="2" name="9" <?php if(isset($_POST['9']) && $_POST['9'] == '2') echo 'checked="checked" ';?> />
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox10" value="3" name="10" <?php if(isset($_POST['10']) && $_POST['10'] == '3') echo 'checked="checked" ';?> />
```

I prepared this:

[a link] (http://jsfiddle.net/ry4k8ve9/)

thanks a lot in advance!! Hope you can help me

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/881166/jquery-checkboxes-like-radiobuttons

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ry4k8ve9/2/

Comment: hey mohit, thanks for the fast answer. the problem is, that I have 10 checkboxes in total, and only checkbox8, checkbox9 and checkbox10 should behave like requested. How can I do this then?

Comment: I got it. I just put them in a div with ID :)

Comment: when I wrap them in a div with id and call by    $('#testing input[type="checkbox"]'); in jfiddle it works, in my program its not working. where do I put the code, in $(document)ready(function() {...  ??

Comment: Yes you need to wrap under document ready function or you can check  browser console for other error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:-

```
var $unique = $('#checkbox8,#checkbox9,#checkbox10');
$unique.click(function() {
   $unique.not(this).removeAttr('checked');    
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ry4k8ve9/3/)

Answer (score 1):

Just add a click event to your checkboxes to turn the others off:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').not(this).prop('checked', false)
})
```